# PetaPoco map comma separated string to a List of string

Tags: c#, .net, orm, petapoco, micro-orm

In the database, I've got a **column** that **contains comma seperated values**, like so:

```
Foo.Bars varchar(100): @;1,5
```

In the  code, the **DTO contains a List<string>**, like so:

```
public class Foo { public List<string> Bars {get; set;} }
```

I'd like **PetaPoco** to **do the conversion** for me.

I've read about the `IMapper` interface but I couldn't find an example of how to use it.
**How can I achieve** the desired result?

Comment: I don't know anything about `PetaPoco`, but from looking at the source code you'll need to implement the `IMapper` interface, and pay specific attention to `GetFromDbConverter`, and then you'll set that mapper on the `Database` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I think:

```
public class ListMapper : IMapper 
{
    public void GetTableInfo(Type t, TableInfo ti)
    {
    }

    public bool MapPropertyToColumn(PropertyInfo pi, ref string columnName, ref bool resultColumn)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public Func<object, object> GetFromDbConverter(PropertyInfo pi, Type sourceType)
    {
        return src => 
            {
                if (sourceType == typeof (string)
                    && pi.PropertyType == typeof (List<string>)
                    && src != null)
                {
                    return ((string) src).Split(';').ToList();
                }
                return src;
            };
    }

    public Func<object, object> GetToDbConverter(Type sourceType)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
Database.Mapper = new ListMapper(); // Mapper is a static property
```

Answer (score 2):

If comma-separated strings are common in your database, then implementing `IMapper` is probably your best option. However, if this only occurs once in your schema, it might be simpler and more maintainable to do something like this:

```
[PetaPoco.Column("Bars")]
public string BarCsvString { get; set; }

[PetaPoco.Ignore]
public IEnumerable<string> Bars { get { return BarCsvString.Split(","); } }
```

(Note - I'm pretty sure `PetaPoco.Ignore` is assumed on read-only properties.)

Comment: That's the first thing I considered but my Foo object stops being a DTO (it implements logic now) and the whole assembly gets a hard dependency to PetaPoco.